# Netbeans Project Deployment Error

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-6.9

My Netbeans is just freaking out. 20 minutes ago it worked fine, but now it is not. I did recall all changes but it is not working.

```
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\TheIntersect\Documents\NetBeansProjects\webWord\build\web&name=webWord&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1 
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Error in generating security policy for webWord -- Error in generating security policy for webWord -- Unable to open Policy file: C:\Users\TheIntersect\.netbeans\7.0\config\GF3\domain1/generated/policy\webWord/webWord\granted.policy. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\TheIntersect\Documents\NetBeansProjects\webWord\nbproject\build-impl.xml:736: 
The module has not been deployed.
  at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:187)
  at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
  at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
  at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
```

Comment: it looks like you are using NB 6.9 to deploy onto GF 3.1... which is not supported.  Do you see anything interesting in the server.log window/file?

Comment: Actually I am using Netbeans 7. Sorry for my careless. It worked 20 minutes ago. Instantly happen something like a magic then it is not working now. But i did upload my project to the another machine. It works fine. I think it is about the netbeans ide files. Now i am reinstalling th Netbeans7 on my comuter. @vkraemer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reainstall the Netbeans IDE and it solverd. But while you are deleting netbeans you should delete all files related about netbeans except project files.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this is still actual, but still may help someone else. 
try to manualy copy `granted.policy` file into `glassfish` appropriate directory

```
(PATH_TO_GF\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\<domain_name>\generated\policy\app_name\app_name>\).
```

If you don't have that file anywhere, just create it with following content

```
grant {
  permission javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission "/";
  permission javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission "/";
};
```